# Which language to do my Regex in?

Tags: c++, regex, perl, voice

I'm an engineering student just trying to create something so I can learn multiple design areas in a swoop - basically my project is working on an inter-com system throughout my house that communicates wirelessly. I may end up doing some sort of voice processing to see if I can parse text like Siri and make it end up calling a function from speaking. This would mean I could possibly have a constant stream of text to parse for a decent duration of time.

My question, then, has a few parts.

1) I assume regex is the route to go to parse text and match a command I want to whatever text was input to my system? If not, please point me in another direction!

2)I understand Perl seems to be the standard, but my background application running will be written in C++ or C#, so I'd prefer to use regex methods in either of those languages.

-I see there is Regex++ or http://www.pcre.org/ , would either of those be sufficient, or is it necessary to use Perl?

What I'm most looking for is speed, I'd prefer not to say something and have to wait a long time for return. I'm sure like most others, speed is key. I see another question on here asking a similar question, but nobody really lists benchmarks. For my application, would regex++ be quick enough assuming I keep my code as simple as possible?

THANKS!

Comment: Your processing time will be on the speech recognition, not the speed of your regular expressions.  You're just looking for simple voice commands / phrases.  Any regular expression parser will be good enough.

Comment: In fact, many speech recognition systems require or benefit from a grammar.  In that case, the output from the speech-to-text would already be known, and you could use ordinary string comparisons.  Fun project, anyway.  I've just got myself a Raspberry-Pi and wondered about wiring my house up...  Wouldn't it be great to have a Star Trek house!  "Computer, dim the lights to 30%", "Computer, play 100 songs for wooing the ladies", "Computer, transport me back to reality"

Comment: Would ordinary string comparisons be able to pick out the number "30" from your phrase there, though? I don't have much experience in string work, and figured regex was the way to go. Would I benefit from rejecting regex and just going that route?

EDIT: Thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: @user1569980 Well, if all you need is basic parsing of words, it might be simpler to just use `strtok`.  So yes, in this case picking the number '30' from the phrase would be realistic, if you tokenised all your words and ran them through a decision tree.  That would be computationally faster than running multiple regular expressions tuned to specific phrases.

Comment: @paddy very useful, thanks for the suggestion. I may try this first and see how ti goes before jumping for regex. I appreciate your insight here!

Comment: I am worried that you seem to be expecting to parse *spoken language* with regular expressions, which is kinda crazy. The process of converting speech to text is an incredibly complex one, but the result is a sequence of language tokens that don't need parsing. Are you planning on using proprietary voice recognition? Also the rules of optimisation say that you should write in the most convenient and readable language and optimise only when necessary. You should start by writing everything in a scripting language like Perl and go from there.

Comment: I plan to use some other software to do the voice work- not something I want to even try to tackle. I'd maybe see if Nuance Dragon works to output a text file of some sort to read, or possibly the voice software that comes with windows. 

Why is it you consider Perl convenient and readable as opposed to C++? I guess I'm just much more used to C++ and find it simple myself, but I haven't done much scripting so it could be a good new world to endeavor in.

Comment: I think it is commonly understood that Perl and similar languages are *vastly* faster to develop in than the likes of C or C++. For one thing there is no compile and link phase before the program can be tested again - you just make a change and run the program. Secondly the code tends to be much shorter - a C++ *Hello World!* is many lines of code. And also memory is allocated and released automatically, which also means there is no risk of errors like access violations that need careful C programming to avoid.

Comment: All of this can come at a cost, and such languages sometimes (depending on the application) run more slowly than a compiled language. But more often than not the speed is plenty fast enough, and any optimisation can be restricted only to one or two bottlenecks.

Comment: Very descriptive answers, thanks for clarifying. I was almost entirely convinced on just doing it all in WPF/C++, but from multiple responses here and your help it appears Perl is my best choice. Much appreciated, since if I chose the wrong language it could turn out to be a HUGE waste of time if I need to change how it is all done.

Answer (score 3):

Regex is an implementation decision. You are miles away from implementation decisions at the moment.

What sort of hardware will you be running? Will the hardware support the language you choose? (e.g. C# has very limited support on anything other than Windows)

It may turn out that you don't need anything as complex as regex.

*Followup based on OP's comments below:*

What your comments are doing is starting to gather some of the requirements for your system.

- Text based commands
- Runnable on windows and OSX
- Platform must be capable of talking to "circuitry"

  - Any specific protocols you need?

The biggest requirements here as it relates to your original question is "Text based commands". Are these 1 word commands or sentances like paddy's comment above?

Comment: The way I'll be using it, the only input to my program would be text. I want to build that logic before I actually care about inputting any voice, although I have circuitry to do so. C++ is what i really want to use, but I simply meant if using another language would prove easier than I wouldn't mind moving over to that.

Comment: Also, I plan to run this on my windows machine, but who knows if it works and a friend wants it who has OSX I may try to flip over to that.

Comment: These would be sentences, a.k.a. if I'm talking in a room with my unit, I would need to be able to detect when I address the system, a la paddy saying "computer" every time. No specific protocol, for right now I'm simply communicating over the serial. When I buy a wireless chip, I will still probably have one plugged into my computer to communicate over the serial port, and then out over the air to my unit wherever it is.

Comment: Also, sorry if I didn't give enough information, please ask away with anything relevant. Thanks a ton!

Comment: All I'm trying to do is draw out of you the answers you need to help build the system. So far I haven't seen a lot that really screams for regex. These answers provide the input to get into the "what" that amon talks about in his answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I guess what I wonder from here is if I use Perl, like my comment to Amon, I'm unsure how easy it will be for me to communicate with my C++ code, and communicating over the serial port. I plan WPF or something similar to try and have a GUI to make a few buttons to control the same intercom type stuff, so I suppose I could try to do it all in Perl?

Answer (score 0):

Perl Regexes are certainly the most advanced regex engine around. But there is the question if you really need that power. Probably not.

I would advise thinking about the **what** first. Class diagramms, your software architecture, algorithms, etc. If you want to write a quick implementation/prototype either use *Python* (beautiful language, likes Windows, thoroughly object-oriented, not slow) or *Perl* (the power of the gods is at your fingertips. There is nothing you can't do. There is module already available for almost anything. But programming Perl is called "hacking" for a reason, and while it works well with Windows, it isn't the fun as on a *nix) or any other fancy scripting language.

After some profiling, think about rewriting performance critical or system level stuff in C/C++. Perl has excellent language bindings; you can write C/C++ *inline*. Regex matching won't be the critical part.

C# isn't very portable, unless you ditch .NET and go for the Mono framework.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. That is all useful, I guess I hadn't ever realized Perl is that useful for coding anything I want. Is it difficult to have both Perl and c++ running in tandem for a single application? Will I run into any obscure troubles?

Comment: If Perl is the host language, no. You would just write single critical functions in C++ using the `Inline` module. But there is some extra work when passing non-trivial arguments or return values between Perl and C++. You can only share the function namespace between the two, there are no shared classes. If your C++ code grows, you might write a library wrapper instead. perl is written in C and has a rich API you can leverage. Just look at the documentation (http://search.cpan.org/~sisyphus/Inline-0.50/Inline.pod) and decide if this may be something for you. Then reconsider ;-)

Comment: @user1569980 Building GUIs with Perl is possible as well. There are bindings to Tk, GTK, Qt, Wx, and the non-portable Win32. No WPF however. In general there is little documentation for these, but it isn't impossible to use. I prefer PerlQt4 because it is just wrapper for the (very rich) C++ libraries and looks native on every platform (and 'cause I use Linux…)

Comment: Whew, OK. This is getting more in depth, so bear with me. I suppose WPF may not be a good choice considering I may port over to OSX. Does this make Perl a better choice to do GUI and everything? Would I really even need C++ then? I see I can run Perl as a win service background to probably do backend things, but as you say I might want C++ for critical functions.

Comment: @user1569980 *"considering I may port"* — porting a Perl/Python program is (probably) *far* easier than porting C++. *"Perl a better choice"* — to get started, yes. Any interpreted language is good for rapid prototyping. *"need C++"* — no. Once you've tasted the freedom, C++ looks archaic and inflexible (although Perl is archaic too, in its way). *"service background"* — using a server/client architecture can be a good idea, although Perl would typically rather be a middle-end. *"critical functions"* — 1. design. 2. code. 3. optimize algorithm. repeat. 4. micro-optimize. 5. use assembler ;-)